# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, type-conversion, int, boolean

Here is a chunk of code in C# on execution it gives me error

> ERROR: "Cannot implicitly convert type “int” to “bool” "

I am unable to understand that I have declared array as `boolean` variable and there is no other `int` variable in my code and it doesn't matter what my function arguments are right?

```
private static bool[,] array = new bool[41, 8];

public void SetArrayElement(int row, int col)
{
    array[row, col] = 1;
}
```

Comment: `array[row, col] = true;` if you insist on `1`, `array[row, col] = 1 == 1;` (better) or `array[row, col] = (bool)1;`

Comment: "there is no other int in my code" - the value you're trying to assign, `1`, is an int.

Comment: Just forget about `C` where `while(1)` was supposed to run forever. its `C#`

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here, this question has everything that is needed. Error message, the minimal and verifyable example to reproduce it and a clear question. To the downvoters: at least explain to him, what he is supposed to change and make it better for the next time....

Comment: @MongZhu I downvoted because "this question does not show any research effort". This is a **basic C# language** issue that can be resolved by taking a little bit of time to learn the basics of the language, instead of not bothering and immediately going for the 'Ask Question' button on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How could i have figured it out that it was C# problem? i have been using C/C++ for more than 4 years and C# seemed pretty much similar, any ways  Thanks everyone for such quick response :)

Comment: @Stijn thank you for taking the time to leave a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion from `int` to `bool` might result in lost information. `1` is an [integer literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) in C#. You can use `true` instead.

```
array[row, col] = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared array as `bool` so you can not assign `integer` to it. You can use `true` or `false` instead.

```
private static bool[,] array = new bool[41, 8]; 

public void SetArrayElement(int row, int col)
{
   array[row, col] = true; // assign either true or false.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unlike **C**, **C#** has special `bool` type and doesn't cast *implicitly `1`* to `true`:

```
  bool myValue = 1; // <- Compile Time Error (C#)
```

Even if *explicit* cast is possible, it's not a good idea:

```
  bool myValue = (bool)1; // It compiles, but not a good style
```

In your case you can just assign `true`

```
  //DONE: static : we don't want "this" here
  public static void SetArrayElement(int row, int col)
  {
     //DONE: validate public method's values
     if (row < array.GetLowerBound(0) || row > array.GetUpperBound(0))
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row));
     else if (col < array.GetLowerBound(1) || col > array.GetUpperBound(1))
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(col)); 

     array[row, col] = true; // true, instead of 1
  }
```